# Check if input has onchange listener and call it manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say i have attached an event to an input, like this :

```
$('#input-address').on('change',function() {
// do something
});
```

Later in my code, i need to check if the 'input-address' has a change listener and call it manually. Something like this :

```
if ($('#input-address').hasOnChangeEvent) $('#input-address').callOnChangeEvent();
```

I know i can do some workaround to achieve this, would be easier for only one time task. But what i'm trying to achieve is a way to do it generically and apply for multiple inputs. Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why does it matter if the `change` event is bound to anything or not? Just raise a `change()` event anyway. If it's bound, your code will execute, if it's not then nothing will happen anyway

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This solved my problem. Please add as a response, i will accept. Thanks !

Comment: I added it for you. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be over-thinking the problem a little. You don't need to check if the event handler is bound at all. If you trigger the event and a handler is bound, then your logic will execute. If you trigger the event and no handler is bound, nothing will happen.

Therefore you can just raise the event using `change()` or `trigger('change')` regardless.

```
$('#input-address').trigger('change');
```